# accessing nested tags in XML files

Tags: javascript, xml

I am making a simple XML parser in javascript using the XMLHttpRequest object, and i am having trouble returning only the tags I want. For example, for [this](http://www.deadstock.ca/collections/adidas/products/adidas-equipment-support-adv-core-black-24.xml) xml file I would like to access and print the variant array (1st one), however my current code is not working.

JavaScript

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function run() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET",     "http://www.deadstock.ca/collections/adidas/products/adidas-equipment-    support-adv-core-black-24.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
        console.log(xhttp.responseText.hash.variant[0]);
    }
  }
}
run();
```

However, this works (returns everything)

```
console.log(xhttp.responseText);
```

I am currently running the file using node.

Comment: `responseText` is a string. It doesn't have a `hash` property. And if you're using [this](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) implementation of XMLHttpRequest, it doesn't have any XML support, which means you need to use something else to actually parse the XML.

Comment: I see. Which implementation would you recommend? The reason I used this one is because when using the built in one (where you did not have to import a library) didnt work (the object is not defined) but in my previous projects it worked fine. What would be the problem?

Comment: You might want to check out [this] for ideas(https://www.quora.com/Does-Node-js-utilize-XMLHttpRequest). I gave an answer that was based on the assumption that you have a JS frontend that could make use of most browser's default `XMLHttpRequest` method since you can easily parse the XML there. But serverside .. there's not really many node modules that'll give it to you as easily. In your instance, you'll need to regex that return string which is not ideal.

Comment: @muffinman32 The library you're using is probably fine for carrying out the request, and once you have the response you can use something like [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom) to parse it. That will give you an XML DOM, which you'd need to access using the DOM interfaces.